# Typescript generic type union not working in methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two types that I want to combine and expect as a function parameter:

```
export type ActionWithValue<ActionType,Value> = {
  type: ActionType;
  value: Value;
};

export type ActionWithPayload<ActionType,Payload> = {
  type: ActionType;
  payload: Payload;
};
```

I unioned them like so:

```
export type Action<ActionType,Payload> = ActionWithPayload<ActionType,Payload> | ActionWithValue<ActionType,Payload>
```

The function type that uses the above type looks like this:

```
export type Reducer<State, ActionType, Payload> = (state: State, action: Action<ActionType, Payload>) => State;
```

When I try to create a function of this type like this:

```
const reducer: Reducer<any, string, any> = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action.value)
}
```

I get an error:
[image]

But when I try to create an object of the unioned type, it works:

```
const a: Action<string, Record<string, any>> = {
    type: '',
    payload: {}
}
```

Any idea why the function is throwing error?

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQWxgQiQCFMBnYAHkONIBUBPMYAPjgG8AoOfuDFbAAXASIkkLNgG4eAXx49QkWIhRosucQyQB1BDAAWANUwAbAK616k6cAA0ZqxzihUSACaUdkitToJJmFOXn4ANwtrMWdrOXk5ZXBoeGRUDBw8W1IDYwAFTGZzCExPQN17BwKiks9Od2AvH2zyKhsgqRDuPjgwQuLSsWqBz3i5fiTVeCE2X1Jyu2Eq-trOAF45-UNTKPaKpeHVuAAfTdyjQ9KF4LZlmtL2JRUUwWE4ACVgT0tcKBoAZRgmFQDk2lTgsVcGwAFJQgagxIDgY44DhdGIWtdOrcIbt2ABKOBrThI1CJHjYUhw1EYjo0OFQZAAc1Bn0pUDKDOZoMwSGY7HW3QErzYYgA5GKHD1%20H17p4xFxFIonsk1JSkNSoF8fmgxJ9vr8aLzmKCuUgWai%20YLYfCUWjJITiUKBOrKBBzMAAHTFJnQ%202kT2ykb46VwLUwSxQJBwOHI%20JAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of type `Action` either looks like this

```
{
  type: ...
  value: ...
}
```

or like this

```
{
  type: ...
  payload: ...
}
```

or even like this

```
{
  type: ...
  payload: ...
  value: ...
}
```

So there is literally no way for the compiler to know, whether the `action` in the `Reducer` will have a `value` property or not, thus the error.

When you create a new instance of `Action` it goes the other way round. Ie, you provide the properites, and the compiler checks, whether the provided properities are sufficient to create one of types in the union ...

You can implement [custom type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like these

```
function isAWV<T, V>(cand: any) : cand is ActionWithValue<T, V> {
  return "value" in cand;
}

function isAWP<T, V>(cand: any) : cand is ActionWithPayload<T, V> {
  return "payload" in cand;
}
```

and then use them in the `Reducer`

```
const reducer: Reducer<any, string, any> = (state, action) => {
  if (isAWV(action))
    console.log(action.value)

  if (isAWP(action))
    console.log(action.payload)
}
```